# How to create a responsive views block in bootstrap?

Tags: theming

I created a content type with one field collection field using [Field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module which accepts up to 4 values.

- Field Collection: Field collection field has 3 fields (text1(40 char), text2(255 char), link). I added one content. Now I have one content with 3 field collection items.
- View: I created a views grid block. Grid settings > number of columns = 1. 
  I selected the above field collection item as field. 
  On the block configuration page, I gave class col-xs-12.

When I visit the page in mobile, I have to scroll to right to see the full content. I gave bootstrap class col-xs-12, why does it not fit into into mobile screen. Can you please help?

**Image-1**

> [image]

**Image-2**

> [image]

Comment: Notice that [tag:bootstrapping] is about the Drupal bootstrap phase, as reported in the tag description.

Answer (score 0):

The grid default format is not responsive, you can trie [Semantic Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/semanticviews)